# Fieldset with `max-height: 0` always overflows on Chrome v87+

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, fieldset

On Chrome 86, a `fieldset` with a `max-height` less than the height of its contents and `overflow: hidden` would hide the contents of that `fieldset`.

> [image: Chrome 86 overflow]

However, on Chrome v87 (`87.0.4280.67`), this apparently changed.

> [image: Chrome 87 overflow]

If a `height` is set that is less than the contents, then it correctly hides the overflow. This bug only appears with `max-height`.

The following snippet will render correctly on Chrome v86 and earlier, Firefox, and Safari. On Chrome 87 the first `fieldset` will overflow.

```css
fieldset {
    /* Reset user-agent styles */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    
    /* Misc */
    background: cyan;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="max-height: 9px">
  This should be half-visible
  (<code>max-height: 9px; overflow: hidden</code>)
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="height: 9px">
  This should also be half-visible
  (<code>height: 9px; overflow: hidden</code>)
</fieldset>
```

Is there a workaround for this? <s>Is there a Chromium bug filed for this? I've tried searching, but haven't found anything definitive.</s> [There is a Chromium ticket, as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65189955/864233).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can add this to the **fieldset**:

`display: -webkit-box;` or `display: -webkit-inline-box;`

```css
fieldset {
    /* Reset user-agent styles */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    
    /* Misc */
    background: cyan;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="max-height: 9px; display: -webkit-box;">
  This should be half-visible
  (<code>max-height: 9px; overflow: hidden</code>)
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="height: 9px">
  This should also be half-visible
  (<code>height: 9px; overflow: hidden</code>)
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented Chromium bug: [Issue 1151858](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151858).

As of December 2020, this bug **has been fixed** and [verified](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151858#c22) that the issue is no longer reproducible.